# Resource cannot be found for content inside of theme folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, themes

My project has a feature to override views and content, if they exist, from a themes folder. The path to the themes folder will vary by site, so my folder structure looks like this:

```
Themes\
    SiteA\
        Content\
            Images\
                logo.png
            screen.css
        Views\
            Home\
                Index.cshtml
```

I am able to successfully override the default view with the site's custom one. However I am unable to access anything in the Content folder for the theme. If I access the file directly at http://localhost:port/Themes/SiteA/Content/screen.css, the resource cannot be found. I also get this error when I try to access anything in the images folder. A co-worker was able to do this for a separate project last year, but I cannot find any notable changes to web.config or other files that would make it work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A co-worker found the problem. When I setup the Themes folders, I copied web.config from Views, which has this option:

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

We changed the path attribute's value from * to *.cshtml and the files are now accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to comment so I'm posting here. Do you have a route that matches the url? Try the RouteDebuger to see what route is hit.

Comment: I added this http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx to the project and it is able to give me a route status for working urls, but not for files under my themes folder. It continues to tell me the resource cannot be found. This has to be an indication of something, but I'm not sure what at the moment.

Comment: Do you have a web.config in any of the Themes subdirectories? ALso, are you testing the site in VS / IIS?

Comment: I had to add web.config to the root Themes folder since we're using Razor, which ended up being the root cause of the problem (thanks to my co-workers). I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions on the underlying folder in the file system? In my experience that's often the cause of being unable to access a resource through a URL - the credentials used by the web site may not be granted access to the underlying resource

Comment: I don't see any discrepancies for the permissions. The folders and CSS files were created within Visual Studio and I have not had an issue accessing them in the past; however, the files were in the Scripts or Content folders rather than my own Themes folder, whose permissions are identical to Content.